# How do I calculate meanlog and sdlog given the quantiles in R

Tags: r, distribution

I am trying to solve for the meanlog and sdlog for a  log-normal distribution in R.

Given that i know 80 and 300 are the 10% and 90% quantiles in a log-normal distribution, how can I solve for the meanlog (which equals 5.04) and the sdlog (0.514)?

I can solve it using guess and test, but I am sure there is a better solution.

Cheers and thanks,

Allan

Comment: This seems to me to be a math question instead of a programming question, so it's better suited for http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The meanlog is calculated as:

```
meanlog <- (log(80) + log(300)) / 2
```

This works because the quantiles are equally spaced from the mean.  Otherwise, you would have to weight them.

The sdlog is calculated as:

```
percentile <- 0.1
sdlog <- (log(80) - meanlog) / qnorm(percentile)
```